# Using the mathutils module from blender in an independent project

Tags: blender

I have a pluggin build for blender which i want to decouple from blender and run independently. The only dependency is the mathutils module. Is there a way to use the mathutils module from blender3d in an independent project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a python package called mathutils, which can be found at https://gitlab.com/ideasman42/blender-mathutils It has all the modules except kdtree. To install simply run

> sudo pip install mathutils

Note that it needs python 3 to run

Answer (score 0):

The header files are written in C++ before being compiled into blender executable so I guess you could download the source files and have a look at it but you might not be able to isolate and recompile what you need in particular because of interdependencies and the way they mapped c++ classes into python objects.